# Landing page in nginx, keep other urls

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx + app in laravel. Right now it is working fine, but I need to show some important announcements to users - so I just create a simple index.html file.

How to setup Nginx to behave as follows:

- when the user type "main URL" - example.org just display a static HTML with the temporary announcement
- when the user types URL to something on the page - example.org/something - then just show him laravel app

Answer (score 1):

**Update @ 2022.05.22**

The following solution is not workable if the requested URI ends with a slash (which is exactly the case when a root request `GET / HTTP/<version>` is made). The reason is the index module (which is called before the static module) see that request URI ended with slash, [checks](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/48086f79ad7d9ac08943312f59215533330617d0/src/http/modules/ngx_http_index_module.c#L356) it for being a directory and returns an error if it isn't. The right solution is to rewrite the URI to make it not ended with a slash, and provided below the not working one.

---

**Not working**

You can use an "exact match" location:

```
server {
    ...
    location = / {
        alias /full/path/to/your/stub.html;
    }
    # rest of the config remains as it was
    location / {
        ...
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Using an `alias` directive you can specify any HTML file from any directory on your server no matter what your `root` directive is set to.

---

**Working**

```
location = / {
    root /path/to/static; # needed only if the path differs from the global root
    rewrite ^ /stub.html break;
}
```

Comment: Setting that with alias /path/to/static/index.html - gives me 500 internal error when reaching "main URL" - example.org, wile other sub URLs works like example.org/something - and laravel app is working fine - just main page is not showing that static index.html

Comment: Basically my problem is to setup two different things:

#landing-static
#    location = / {
#       alias /var/www/html/landing/public/;
#       try_files $uri /index.html
#}


with this:

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

Comment: @beria-pl Most probably it is too late, but I'm finally fixed this one.

Comment: how you was able to mange it?